# Auto populate Map with subclasses using Spring Framework

Tags: spring

I have an abstract class A with a few sub classes B, C, D and I would like to have a Map with Spring auto injecting all the sub classes into a Map.

I'm about to make many sub classes from A and I do not want to after creating them to also populate the XML so Spring can put them in a Map (Its double work and tedious). I want Spring to take all those sub classes and auto put them in the Map without the bulky XML.

I understand for the Map I need to give a key to each instance of the sub class bean.

So have this so far:

```html
public abstract class A{}
    
@Bean(name = "Bbean")
public class B extends A{}
    
@Bean(name = "Cbean")
public class C extends A{}
    
@Bean(name = "Dbean")
public class D extends A{}
```

And finally I want this to work and not be null when I reference it:

```
 @Autowired
 private Map<String, A> map;
```

How do I set this up in Spring Framework?

Comment: Do you really need a map? With a list this is just working. Havent used maps for autowiring yet.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, you want your beans auto-detected and then to collect them automatically. 
So annotate your B, C, D classes with @Component -like annotations (e.g. @Component, @Service, @Repository, @Controller etc.), and then use @ComponentScan to detect them. (@Bean is used for other purposes, you didn't use it properly in your example). 
Then you collect all beans of type A with @Autowired annotation:

```
@Autowired List<A> allAs;
```

Now you want to make a map, so make all these beans bean name-aware:

```
class A implements BeanNameAware {...}
```

And finally you create a map from your @Autowired list:

```
class AsMapHolder implements InitializingBean {
    @Autowired private List<A> allAs;
    private Map<String, A> nameToA = new LinkedHashMap<String, A>();
    @Override void afterPropertiesSet() {
        for (A a: allAs) {
            nameToA.put(a.getName(), a); //getName() is from BeanNameAware, populated automatically
        }
    }
}
```

It should work.

**Update**: Simply '***@Autowired Map beanNameToA;***' should work as well

Comment: Thanks it worked, I'm just thinking if you can autowire a list with a one liner as you did, surely one can autowire a map as per my requirements - without all that boilerplate code you wrote. I don't have enough creds to vote you up.

Comment: The question is why do you need it. Seems like you create another small  Spring container. Note that you can always get any bean by its name from the Spring application context, just let your bean implement ApplicationContextAware interface.